# Trying to append a char string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variables

I know this is a basic question but I can't seem to append a char string (\r\n) to another.  I have tried using arrays (strcpy) and string objects but with no progress.  To send a string to a Java applet I need to append the \r\n characters or it will just sit and wait for them.  When I use a stirng with the c_str() function I get a

> C:\ucdhb2\gaia\async_ssl\no4\basic.cpp|163|error: request for member
>   'c_str' in 'readit', which is of non-class type 'std::string*'|

error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
        char readit[45];

        cin >> readit;

        strcpy( readit, "\r\n" );

        SSL_write( ssl, readit, strlen(readit));   // This doesn't work 
//      SSL_write( ssl, "this works\n\r", strlen("this works\n\r"));  // This works
```

Comment: Unrelated to you problem, but you should use strncpy() instead of strcpy() in pretty much all cases to avoid overflows.

Comment: Why use a `std::string *`? If you absolutely have to, use `readit->c_str()`

Comment: `strcpy` _copies_ `"\r\n"` to readit instead of _concatenating_. Change `strcpy` with `strcat`.

Comment: @KevinMangold: Rather the opposite -- `strncpy` is almost *never* what anybody really wants. Limiting the amount copied is fine, but `strncpy` gets just about everything wrong.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Not sure what you mean? That recommendation is from a security perspective.

Comment: @KevinMangold: 1) if there's not enough space for the whole source string, `strncpy` leaves the destination un-terminated. 2) if there's extra space, it zero-fills all the unused space. The second is only annoying and useless, but the first is dangerous and means that `strncpy` is rarely useful (or an improvement over anything, or secure in any meaningful way).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, understood and this is probably a conversation better off elsewhere, but then how would you prepare for buffer overflows--manually check lengths of everything?

Comment: @KevinMangold: In C++ I'd generally use `std::string`. In C, you can use `sprintf`, specifying the buffer size, like: `char buffer[20]; sprintf(buffer, "%19s", source_string);`. That prevents buffer overflow and still assures the destination is zero terminated (and doesn't waste time zero filling unused space either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `string` should be what you need.

```
std::string readit;
std::getline(std::cin, readit);
readit += "\r\n";
SSL_write(ssl, readit.data(), readit.size());
```

As other commentators have noted, your sample code needed to use `strcat` rather than `strcpy`. But, if you go with using `char` arrays, you will need to check for buffer overflow. `std::string` won't overflow.

Comment: Agreed, the only issue here was confusion over how to use pointers.

Comment: I am only reciving one word and the rest is not there when I sent it across the network?  Is this related or do I have another problem?

Comment: This is working for me... somewhat, but I seem to only get one word across the network.. is this a seperate question?

Comment: Are you using SSL in blocking or non-blocking mode? In anycase, I think it is a different question. Print the string to a file to see if the appended bytes are there.

Comment: Then you need to check the return value of `SSL_write` to see if it returned an error, and then check the error.  If it is `WANT_READ` or `WANT_WRITE`, then wait in select accordingly, and then retry the `SSL_write` after `select` returns. This is definitely a different question.

Comment: This isn't from SSL at all. It's just that `cin >> some_string` only reads up to the first white-space character. If you want more, consider something like `std::getline` instead.

Comment: @user1220811: Jerry Coffin is right, `cin >> readit` will only return a word.

Comment: @user1220811: Thanks for accepting my answer, +1 on your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try strcat function, this will concate two string

Comment: ^ This is much better solution than what I previous recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your strcpy, which copies one string to another, use:

```
char* str = new char[100];
sprintf(str, "%s\r\n", readit);
```